# Rails: Nested form for many-to-one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models: Interview and Interviewee.

There is a many to one relation between Interview and Interviewee.

I want to be able to add a new Interviewee when creating a new Interview using `/interviews/new` route. If the Interviewee was already present, the newly created interview should be linked to it.

**In other words, I want to create a nested form for "belongs_to" relation. Precisely, creating a parent or linking to an existing one using the form for it's child**. Here is my code:

interview.rb

```
class Interview < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :interviewee, inverse_of: :interviews
 has_many :meetings
 has_many :interviewers, through: :meetings
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :interviewee
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :interviewers
end
```

interviewee.rb

```
class Interviewee < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :interviews, inverse_of: :interviewee
end
```

Interviews Controller

```
class InterviewsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @interviews = Interview.all
    end

    def new
        @interview = Interview.new
        #2.times {@interview.interviewers.build}
        @interview.interviewers.build
        #@interview.interviewee.build
    end

    def create
        #render plain: params[:interview].inspect
        @interview = Interview.new(interview_params)

        @interview.save
        redirect_to @interview
    end

    private
        def interview_params
            params.require(:interview).permit(
                :title, :date, :start_time, :end_time,
                interviewee_attributes: [:id, :email],
                interviewers_attributes: [:id, :email]
            )
        end
end
```

interview - new.html.erb

```
<h1>Schedule a New Interview</h1>

<%= form_for @interview, url: interviews_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_field :date %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :start_time %><br>
    <%= f.time_field :start_time %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :end_time %><br>
    <%= f.time_field :end_time %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :interviewee do |interviewee| %>
    <p>
        Interviewee Email:<br>
        <%= interviewee.text_field :email %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :interviewers do |interviewer| %>
    <p>
        Interviewer Emails:<br>
        <%= interviewer.text_area :email %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

For some reason, the email textbox for Interviewee is not shown in the view. At the same time, textbox for Interviewers (many to many with Interview) is shown. Can anyone shed some light on this ? I couldn't find out about how to do this in the official Rails "Form-helpers" guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason, the email textbox for Interviewee is not shown in the
>   view.

You need to **build** the *nested object* in the `new` method.

```
def new
  @interview = Interview.new
  #2.times {@interview.interviewers.build}
  @interview.interviewers.build
  @interview.build_interviewee #here
end
```

so that `@interview` will contain *attributes* of *nested associatio*n and then those will be available for the *form builder*

Alternatively, you can also do it like below

```
<%= f.fields_for :interviewee, @interview.build_interviewee do |interviewee| %>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked :). I accept this answer. What if I want to check if an Interviewee (parent) with given attributes already exist and would simply like to link the Interview (child) to it ? How to write such a method for it.

Comment: Also, please do upvote this question as it may be helpful to other too and it is something which isn't mentioned in the rails official guides :)